# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'AccessibilityInfo' in 'app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, react-native, storybook

It looks like at-loader fails to load all the modules required.
What can I do make the loader be aware of modules like 'AccessibilityInfo' in react-native?

Eg:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'AccessibilityInfo' in 'app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native'
```

**npm run storybook**

```
$ start-storybook start -p 7007 -c .storybook

info @storybook/react v3.3.9
info
Failed to load ./.env.
info => Loading custom .babelrc
info => Loading custom webpack config (full-control mode).
 26% building modules 136/147 modules 11 active ...-v2/node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.js
[at-loader] Using typescript@2.5.3 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from app/tsconfig.json.

 94% asset optimization
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Checking finished with 185 errors
webpack built c763d68b78931e9f2589 in 7072ms
Hash: c763d68b78931e9f2589
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 7072ms
                       Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    static/manager.bundle.js    2.63 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  manager
    static/preview.bundle.js    1.62 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  preview
static/manager.bundle.js.map    3.22 MB       0  [emitted]         manager
static/preview.bundle.js.map    1.92 MB       1  [emitted]         preview
                  index.html     1.2 kB          [emitted]
                 iframe.html  583 bytes          [emitted]
 [205] ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/polyfills.js 113 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [517] multi ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/addons.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/client/manager/index.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
 [518] ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/addons.js 105 bytes {0} [built]
 [519] ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/register.js 30 bytes {0} [built]
 [520] ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/register.js 30 bytes {0} [built]
 [521] ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/client/manager/index.js 404 bytes {0} [built]
 [729] ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/client/manager/provider.js 3.31 kB {0} [built]
 [731] multi ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/globals.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true ./.storybook/config.js 64 bytes {1} [built]
 [732] ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/globals.js 105 bytes {1} [built]
 [733] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true 7.35 kB {1} [built]
 [737] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {1} [built]
 [739] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client-overlay.js 2.21 kB {1} [built]
 [744] (webpack)-hot-middleware/process-update.js 4.33 kB {1} [built]
 [745] ./.storybook/config.js 94 bytes {1} [built]
 [817] ./stories/index.js 925 bytes {1} [built]
    + 807 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'AccessibilityInfo' in 'app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js 19:35-63
 @ ./src/components/Question.tsx
 @ ./stories/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/globals.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true ./.storybook/config.js
```

**/src/components/Question.tsx**

```
  1 import * as React from "react"
  2 import { StyleProp, StyleSheet, Text, ViewStyle } from "react-native"
  3 import { colors } from "../styles/colors"
  4 import { fonts } from "../styles/fonts"
  5
  6 export interface IProps {
  7   style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
  8   onPress?: () => void
  9 }
 10
 11 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 12   title: {
 13     color: colors.black,
 14     fontFamily: fonts.bold,
 15     fontSize: 24,
 16     fontWeight: "bold",
 17     marginBottom: 10,
 18     textAlign: "center",
 19   },
 20 })
 21
 22 export const Question: React.SFC<IProps> = ({ style, ...otherProps }) => (
 23   <Text style={ [styles.title, style] }> { otherProps.children } </Text >
 24 )
```

**babelrc**

```
  1 {
  2   "presets": [
  3     "react-native"
  4   ]
  5 }
```

**stories/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import Question from '../src/components/Question';

storiesOf('Question', module)
  .add('with text', () => (
    <Question onPress={action('clicked')}>Hello Button</Question>
  ))
  .add('with some emoji', () => (
    <Question onPress={action('clicked')}>   </Question>
  ));
```

**.storybook/webpack.config.js**

```
// load the default config generator.
const genDefaultConfig = require('@storybook/react/dist/server/config/defaults/webpack.config.js');
module.exports = (baseConfig, env) => {
  const config = genDefaultConfig(baseConfig, env);
  // Extend it as you need.
  // For example, add typescript loader:
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader')
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
  return config;
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation:  */
    "jsx": "react",                           /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "./lib",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    "noImplicitThis": false,                  /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */

    /* Additional Checks */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "baseUrl": ".",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "*.ios", "*.android"]
    }                                         /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */

    /* Source Map Options */

    /* Experimental Options */
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./src/node_modules/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `import {storiesOf} from '@storybook/react-native'`?

Comment: You're right! I added it but it still fails with the same error.  :(

Comment: What version of react-native are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.51.0

Comment: Upgraded to 0.52.0. Same error.

Comment: Haven't really come across this issue myself, but it seems plenty of others have (but I'm sure you've read through this yourself already)
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14209

Comment: Doesn't seem to be reliably resovable, sadly

Comment: @martins were you able to resolve this? I have the same issue

Comment: @GraemePaul No, I stopped trying to get storybook to work. :(